# How to make imageView background change one time

Tags: android, kotlin

```
if (buttonClicked.contains(1) && buttonClicked.contains(2)) {
    if (playerOneLastClicked) {
        imgViewBackground1.setImageResource(R.drawable.rca)
    } else {
        imgViewBackground1.setImageResource(R.drawable.wac)
    }
}

if (buttonClicked.contains(3) && buttonClicked.contains(4) && buttonClicked.contains(5)) {
    if (playerOneLastClicked) {
        imgViewBackground2.setImageResource(R.drawable.rca)
    } else {
        imgViewBackground4.setImageResource(R.drawable.wac)
    }
}
```

when **player1** or **player2** last click in `(buttonClicked.contains(1) && buttonClicked.contains(2)) imgViewBackgound1` change but when the players click button 3,4 or 5 `imgViewBackground` keep changing.

I want when `imgViewBackground1` take `(R.drawable.rca)` or `(R.drawable.wac)` don't change any more.

Comment: Will your `imgViewBackgroundX` already have a bitmap prior to setting this way? (in other words, will it be null or not?)

Comment: when imgViewBackground set background rca or wac i want be not enable for don't change any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `imgViewBackground` is not going to have an imageview you could just add an extra check e.g.

```
if (imgViewBackground1.drawable == null) {
     if (playerOneLastClicked) {
                imgViewBackground1.setImageResource(R.drawable.rca)
            } else {
                imgViewBackground1.setImageResource(R.drawable.wac)
            }
    }
}
```

or if it would have an imageview already and you don't want it set again

```
if (imgViewBackground1.drawable != resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.rcs, null) 
    || imgViewBackground1.drawable != resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.wac, null))
    if (playerOneLastClicked) {
                    imgViewBackground1.setImageResource(R.drawable.rca)
                } else {
                    imgViewBackground1.setImageResource(R.drawable.wac)
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i did  if (playerOneLastClicked && imgViewBackground1.drawable == null)  imgViewBackground1 set only (R.drawable.wac)

Comment: when i did what you say first and seconde imgViewBackground1 don't show image (rca , wac) never

Comment: Does that mean you set the `imgViewBackground1` before? So the `imgViewBackground1.drawable` wouldn't be null ? If so try my second suggestion

Comment: i did your  second suggestion the image appears but he keep change when i click other button. how i set imgViewBackground1 null to do your first suggestion

Comment: Change the `&&` to `||`

Comment: same thing the image keep change when other button clicked

Comment: i want set imgViewBackground1 be null to do your first suggestion

Comment: It should be by default unless you set it in the xml or programatically before

Comment: ok i will search for how i set imgView be null. thank you so much for your help

Comment: No problem mate